# Multiple smart contracts with single account

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, multi-index

I have three smart contracts (A, B, C) and one account (X). As the requirement is I just need only one authority (administrator) who is going to manage all these smart contracts data. So I deployed these smart contracts using the same account. Whenever I need to manage data from table I need to deploy the particular smart contract first. For eg.

> A, B and C smart contracts are deployed using account X. Data in
>   multi-index tables are saved respectively. In Latest, C is deployed so
>   now X can only access multi-index table and Actions of C. Now, if I
>   want to manage data of A smart contract, at this level for accessing
>   the table and Actions of A I need to deploy A again. So, the table is
>   in X's abi and can access now. Similarly for B.

Otherwise it gives error as,

```
Error 3060003: Contract Table Query Exception
Most likely, the given table doesn't exist in the blockchain.
Error Details:
Table documents is not specified in the ABI
```

My question is every time I need to manage data of any table, do I need to deploy its smart contract first? I don't want three different accounts for A, B and C. Please guide and suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy only one contract per account. If you deploy new contract on your account, existing contract is removed, but its data saved via multi_index table are alive. You need to merge three contracts into one.

Easiest way to do this is putting all methods of three contracts into one class.

Second, you can use multiple contract classes in one wasm, but you need to write down your own `apply()` function to dispatch action correctly. `apply()` is an entry point of eosio contract like `main()`, and it would be generated automatically unless you declare it explicitly. Refer to [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/a6b8d3fc289d46f4612588cdd7223a3d549238f6/libraries/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/dispatcher.hpp). This way requires advanced knowledge about eos contract compilation, or you will fail to generate ABI correctly.

Third, you don't like it, but you can make three accounts and set admin account's active to each account's active permission instead of key.

```
contract1:
  permission:
    active: 1 1 admin@active
            1 1 EOS8BQAdzgacbacUjuUwYR1wEMUcEPLu1DpucmD4xNSLhtXuDSAHe

contract2:
  permission:
    active: 1 1 admin@active

...
```

Comment: For the third option, In each smart contract, I need to check the authority bypassing admin account name. Now I am doing **require_auth(_self);**. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but you need to sign transaction with key of admin@active, but send action with contract1@active. (If you want to send action to contract1) If you don't want to do that, you can hard-code require_auth("admin_account_name"_n); or make a singleton to store admin account name.

Comment: Okay thank you!

Comment: Can you please guide on the second option?

Comment: Refer [here](https://github.com/conr2d/eosio-contract-practice/tree/dispatch-multiple-classes). This is a very simple example. Please NEVER try this in product until you understand its behavior completely. There was a theft that EOS worth $100K was stolen because of insecure dispatcher.

Comment: `[[eosio::on_notify]]` will not work if you add `apply()`. You need to handle notifications (from other contract) by yourself. You can use `receiver` and `code` to know from where action comes.

Comment: you passed `multi.cpp` class name in `hpp` files and access them. In my case what will be the `hpp` files. I have more than three smart contracts to deal with. Each smart contract's CPP, ABI and WASM are available. But I didn't get about hpp files. And also the dispatcher is to be added in each smart contract?

Comment: It seems that you're not familiar with c++. You can split each cpp into hpp and cpp. Put only class declaration in header (.hpp) and its implementation in source (.cpp). Refer to eosio.token contract. Your three contracts source files will be compiled into one WASM and ABI. If you don't know how to separate hpp from cpp, you can include other cpp file from cpp like `#include "otherfile.cpp"`, but I can't say it always works without seeing your code directly. The only thing I can say is that you need only one dispatcher (`apply()`) for all.

Comment: Hey @conr2d, Thank you so much for your guidance. I understand your answers. Got the things now. Appreciate your help. It worked!

Comment: Only, the next part is the security concern. Do I need to change the dispatcher code or no need?

Comment: Security holes related to dispatcher are usually about notification handler. If you don't have a plan to handle notifications (If you are a sender or recipient of `eosio.token::transfer`, you will get notification from `eosio.token` contract), my example will work.

Comment: Okay. Thanx a lot.